# Action without Page_Load

Tags: .net, asp.net

Is there anyway to perform a timely action in ASP.NET using a timer but without page load. Simply to run some silent back ground activities.

Do .ascx files help me running such activities?

Comment: According http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/f/aspxfile.htm, this kind of file contains source code for asp.net programming.

Comment: @reporter - Did you read my question first.

Comment: Yes, I read your question and I answered your second question with this link.

Comment: @reporter - second question is about .ascx not .aspx

Comment: sry, when I used google, it did change my keywords to aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery like below

```
window.setInterval(yourfunction, 10000);

function yourfunction() { alert('test'); }
```

or use [Timer Control in AJAX](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/using_the_ajax_timer_control_a.html)

**EDIT:**

if you don't need to load any page then try this out ["Easy Background Tasks in ASP.NET"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)

Comment: For for this also I have to open a page. What I really mean is. Without opening any web page. The queries must take place independent to events. In simple I need a silent event.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of background activities you'd like to run, but maybe you can use the jQuery timer plugin? Use the .Everytime method :

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run this background activities on client side I recommend to look over @stekkie answer.

If you need to run on server side, you could use UpdatePanel with a timer to accomplish your objective. Check this for more details on how to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400(v=Expression.40).aspx

You can just have this update panel with nothing inside it and on server side, you just implement the  OnTick event of the timer control and run the code you need.

.ascx files are not going to help you run background activities.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of background activities you're looking to run. Page level is usually not the place to perform background operations. From the way you're describing it, it sounds like you should look into creating a service for your background operations.